# How can I see if a login failed in the Office 365 audit log?

Tags: office365

How can I see if a login failed in the Office 365 audit log? I get this entry in the audit log:

```
ForeignRealmIndexLogonInitialAuthUsingADFSFederatedToken
```

I'm not an Office 365 pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to see the failed login activities.

Login operation is denoted by more than 10 events. Following are few of the known login events.

- UserLoggedIn
- UserLoginFailed
- PasswordLogonInitialAuthUsingPassword
- foreignrealmindexlogoncookiecopyusingdatoken
- foreignrealmindexlogoncookiecopyusingsha1remembermypassword
- foreignrealmindexlogoninitialauthusingadfsfederatedtoken
- passwordlogoncookiecopyusingdatoken
- passwordlogoninitialauthusingadfsfederatedtoken
- passwordlogonsilentreauthusingdatoken

To check the login failure cases, you need to verify the result status for the above operations.

**Easy Solution:**

You can try the [AdminDroid Office 365 Auditing Tool](http://admindroid.com) to get the login activities either by report or through the visually appealing dashboards.

[image: Login Activities Dashboard]
[image]